# How to get rock solid Eloquent relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have been building a medium-sized application and am now enabling lots of secondary use cases.  This means relying more on events and listeners, and touching objects multiple times in a single request.

During this process there have been a few cases where I have been surprised by the behaviour of Eloquent relationships.  Obviously when I'm receiving an object as an argument to an event handler I may not know its detailed history, so I need to understand when/how I can rely on it (and when/how not).

Take this case where I have a parent entity, and a number of children.  Here's the Eloquent relationship on the parent:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Model\Child::class);
}
```

Elsewhere in the parent I have a method for adding children, something like this:

```
public function addChildren(array $data) 
{
    $children = [];

    foreach ($data as $child) {
      $children[] = new Child($child);
    }

    $this->children()->saveMany($children);
}
```

Later in the request cycle I am testing some conditions on the parent, and where truthy, I get the children using `$parent->children`, and do some further work with them.

That was working fine until someone pointed out a business rule I had missed - you can't add children in this manner if the parent already has children.  In order to handle this, I put a simple test at the top of the `addChildren()` method:

```
public function addChildren(array $data)
{
    if(count($this->children)) { 
       throw new \Exception('Can not add children where they already exist');
    }

    // remainder of the method goes here...
}
```

When I added this code I started to get unexpected results.  Upon investigation I found that by counting the children early in the method (which obviously realises the relationship) it affected how the relationship would later behave.

I tried dumping the value of `$parent->children` after the method was run.  If I exclude the code that counts the children first, I get what I expect - a collection of my newly added children.  However, if I include the counting code, I get an empty array.

So, the question is:

- Am I using the relationships wrong?
- Am I expecting too much of the relationships?
- Should I always unset and reload a relationship if I don't know the history of the object in the context of the current request?
- Do I need to understand Eloquent at a deeper level to be confident with more complex use cases?
- Are there a few simple rules that would help me master it?
- Something else...?

I absolutely love Laravel so am keen to understand this burning question...

Edit:

For anyone who is reading this post, I ended up queuing some of the non-core parts of the use case.  This was a good move for performance, and feels right in terms of decoupling.  Because Laravel serialises the Eloquent model id (and not the model itself), it gave me the effect I was looking for in a reasonably elegant manner.

Comment: You may try refreshing `$this` instance during the check. `$this->fresh('children')`, or better yet do a has check `$this->has('children')->get()` or `$this->children()->exists()` - it executes query against database.

Comment: `fresh` returns a new instance ... `load` loads relationships ... `refresh` refreshes the current instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not using relationships in the wrong way and neither are you expecting too much.

With the idea of a REST, most of the time you shouldn't really ever find yourself in the situation where you want to load a relationship, add to it, and then return the new relationship. If you've got a store or update route then you don't need to load the relationship beforehand (unless you have a specific use case) and for the rest of the time you should just be calling the relationship and returning the results.

If, for whatever reason, you need to modify a relationship (I'm sure there are plenty of reasons) and then return the results you can always just reload the relationship e.g.

```
$parent->fresh('children');
```

Alternatively, if you're just wanting to count the children you can use a count query instead of getting all of the `children`:

```
$parent->children()->count();
```

This will not load the relationship but will let you know how many children you have.